# Fresh install windows 7 64bit hangs after formatting

Tags: windows-7, boot

My PC Build is the following

- Q8200 Intel Core 2 Quad
- 5 GB DDR2 RAM (2x2GB , 1x1GB)
- 700GB sataII
- HDD nVidia geForce gt 220
- ASUS: IPIBL-LA motherboard
- usbmouse&keyboard

I created a bootable USB with legit copy of windows 7 Ultimate 64bit, i tried to boot with 1st priority set to USB drive, it started with the progress bar slowly being completed, after that it just stuck to "starting windows", my mouse&keyboard were "frozen".
after a few attempts i managed to get passed it, the installation screen for windows 7 to select drive popped up, windows 7 properly recognized my hdd and its partitions , i selected the partition that i prepared for it, and it started expanding files, after that it restarted, and the problem reappeared

it just hangs in "starting windows" with keyboard&mouse frozen.

i also tried scanning HDD & RAM for errors , i runned all tests twice, and nothing showed up.
any thought on why this happens?

thank you for your time

Comment: 5gb ram seems like an odd amount. Are you sure your motherboard accepts that increment of memory?

Comment: i removed 1 GB from the 3rd slot and place 2gb,empty,2gb,empty and everything worked smoothly, why i can't have 5GB if i place it to the empty slot in current configuration won't it work?

Comment: You have to follow what the motherboard allows for memory configurations.